# Scraping specific attribute in tr tag

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, scrape

```
allId=soup.find_all("tr","data-id")
```

[image: HTML Code]

I just take *data-id*'s values. How can I scrape these tags?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fetch value of data-id try this.

```
allId=soup.find_all("tr",attrs={"data-id" : True})
for item in allId:
    print(item['data-id'])
```

You can also use css selector.

```
allId=soup.select("tr[data-id]")
for item in allId:
    print(item['data-id'])
```